# GAE File upload/download via HTTP (no UI needed): Already implemented as open source?

Tags: google-app-engine, open-source, amazon-s3

My webapp sometimes needs to store a dump (~20MB file).
My webapp is running on a [read-only](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) filesystem so it has to upload the file (presumably via HTTP POST) to a third-party service, and I am considering Google App Engine for this.

Coding it by myself is not hard, but **is there already an open source project for this?**

- File upload via HTTP POST
- File download via HTTP GET
- No user interface needed
- No authentication needed

*Note: Amazon S3 would cost almost nothing, but I would rather not give my credit card details.*

Comment: A service like Google Developer Storage or S3 sounds like exactly what you're looking for. Why the aversion to giving your billing details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find, so I implemented it, and made it open source:

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Troois

You HTTP POST the file and receive a key as the reply.
Then you can download the file using the key.